# linter error static method lodash typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have this error reported by the `linter` on the call to `_.isEqual` :

[`https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.22.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/unbound-method.md`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.22.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/unbound-method.md)

Do you know how I can correct this error?

```
const liste = computed(() => { return _.uniqWith(_.map(liste.value, 'contrat'), _.isEqual) })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some options:

1. As `_.isEqual` does not use `this` inside its body you may safely ignore this rule in this particular case:

   ```ts
   /* eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/unbound-method */
   const liste = computed(() => { return _.uniqWith(_.map(liste.value, 'contrat'), _.isEqual) })
   ```
2. You may use wrapping function to preserve calling context:

   ```ts
   const liste = computed(() => { return _.uniqWith(_.map(liste.value, 'contrat'), (a, b) => _.isEqual(a, b)) })
   ```
3. Explicitly bind calling context. Kind of ugly but does the job:

   ```ts
   const liste = computed(() => { return _.uniqWith(_.map(liste.value, 'contrat'), _.isEqual.bind(_)) })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For me replace package [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) with [`lodash-es`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) and [`@types/lodash-es`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash-es) will eliminate this violation: https://github.com/n0099/open-tbm/commit/47254c7824bc8fd821562d3fd049c6f2ec11f63a