# lodash's flow() breaks add() in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, lodash, eslint

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const x = _.add(3, 2) // no linting error

const foo = _.flow(
  _.add, // @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
  square,
)
```

Full error description at https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/unbound-method.md.

Why does using lodash's flow() break it's own add() and is there a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't replicate that with Typescript Version 4.3.2. Which version of Typescript do you use? Also, which version of lodash and @types/lodash do you use?

Comment: For me replace package [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) with [`lodash-es`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) and [`@types/lodash-es`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash-es) will eliminate this violation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67882654/linter-error-static-method-lodash-typescript/77965509#77965509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this error comes from the [recommended-requiring-type-checking](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/79b510c00f25d76daf741936682e1222b0c994b5/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended-requiring-type-checking.ts#L24) eslint configuration.

This configuration is more opinionated than the base typescript eslint. As a result, I feel comfortable overriding this rule:

`.eslintrc.js`

```
...
rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/unbound-method': 'off', // conflicts with lodash's add()
}
```